# Powershell: Get users with multiple specified Product Licences

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to get output from O365 via PowerShell for users with specific product licenses assigned.

There's plenty of articles out there of how to get this information but not found information explaining how to grab users with multiple specified products.

So far I have the following (taken from [here](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/get-office-365-users-specific-license-type-via-powershell/)):

```
Get-MsolUser -All | 
Where-Object {
    ($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "EXCHANGEENTERPRISE" `
    -and ($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "EMS" `
    -and ($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -notmatch "ENTERPRISEPACK"
} | 
Select-Object displayname,userprincipalname,{$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId} | 
Export-Csv "C:\Temp\EOP2+EMSLicensedUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

However, this still shows users who have ENTERPRISEPACK assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the reformat. Much easier to read but should there be the character "`" after the first two SkuID lines?

Comment: No, explicit line continuation via backtick is only necessary when PowerShell cannot be sure whether the line continues or not. The way I broke the lines here there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't like it unless I include the backtick. It complains that -and is not a recognized cmdlet. Not to worry though as including this character allows it to go through.

Comment: Weird, my PowerShell ISE has no problem with that. Well, add the back-ticks then.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it is obviously not helping you.

Comment: Ok, turns out that changes were made to licensing by someone else during my testing. Your amendments/suggestions work as intended with the extra parenthesis and my observation that this wasn't working was simply down to the original output occurring before these changes were made by another person. If you still have your post content please do put this back up and I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for your patience and effort helping me with this. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, answer restored. I removed it to increase the chance that somebody else answers who knows more about the Office365 Powershell cmdlets than I do – questions with zero answers might attract more eyeballs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell operators do not work like you think they do.

`.AccountSkuId` is an *array* of values. Doing `AccountSkuId -notmatch "ENTERPRISEPACK"` does not tell you whether `"ENTERPRISEPACK"` is contained in that array or not. It gives you all the values from that array that do not match `"ENTERPRISEPACK"`.

It's a **filter**. Try executing `"1","2","3" -notmatch "3"` to see what I mean.

Therefore, if even one value in `AccountSkuId` does not match `"ENTERPRISEPACK"`, you still get some values back, and "some values" (i.e. a non-empty list) evaluates to `$true` in a Boolean expression.

You wanted to write this:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | 
Where-Object {
    ($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "EXCHANGEENTERPRISE" 
    -and ($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "EMS" 
    -and -not (($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "ENTERPRISEPACK")
} | 
Select-Object displayname,userprincipalname,{$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId} | 
Export-Csv "C:\Temp\EOP2+EMSLicensedUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Note the change. `($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "ENTERPRISEPACK"` gives you all values that match `"ENTERPRISEPACK"` (normally 1 or 0) and the `-not` simply negates that result.

---

Other things to try with PowerShell operators:

- `1,2,2,3 -eq 2`
- `1,2,2,3 -ne 2`
- `1,2,2,3 -gt 1`
- `"hallo","hello","foo" -like "*ll*"`
- `"hallo","hello","foo" -replace 'l','L'`

Keep in mind that PowerShell operates on lists when it can. A single value is nothing but a list of length 1.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation of this. After a good think about it I can see what you mean, however, still doesn't appear to be working as required. When the above is run it returns nothing but there are users that have just "tenent:EMS tenent:ENTERPRISEPACK" present so would expect these to also be returned. If again, this is not how it works then how would I get the intended results?

Comment: I was only assuming that  `AccountSkuId` was an array. Is it not?

Comment: Also, `"tenent:EMS tenent:ENTERPRISEPACK"` does match `"ENTERPRISEPACK"`, and we are excluding those values. I thought that was the whole point of this.

Comment: No it's not. The above is the full script excluding the connecting to the MS Online part. This command was simply taken from a tech article but as mentioned, these examples didn't explain how to return multiple valued results.

Comment: The template of this script explained that -match could be used so the full term didn't need to be specified. Some results have the plans in different orders, not how shown above, so needed something that searched for results containing the word rather than listing every combination.

Comment: I'm confused. The last line in your question reads *"However, this still shows users who have ENTERPRISEPACK assigned."* and to me that means you don't want to see those users. And now you say removing those users was not the point of your question? (Also, *"so far, I have the following"* means that you have written the code yourself. If you just copied it from somewhere and are not even sure if it even does what you want, say so.)

Comment: Yes, I want the results to simply show users with "tenent:EXCHANGEENTERPRISE tenent:EMS" or any combination of the two but exclude any users that also have "tenent:ENTERPRISEPACK" present. When I run the above that you've supplied, no results are returned at all but would expect users with just the two specified above assigned to be returned but they're not. "So far, I have the following" simply means that I have obtained the following one way or another and modified to suit my needs. I thought I had got it working as I wanted but noticed it wasn't which is why I then posted here.

Comment: So, back to my first comment: "I was only assuming that `AccountSkuId` was an array. Is it not?" - I don't have the Office365 cmdlets installed, but I know how PowerShell works. So in order to see what's wrong I need to know exactly what data you are working with.

Comment: No it's not an array. I did answer this above. I'm assuming it's an attribute and the basis of the script started from [Get Office 365 users with a specific license type via Powershell](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/get-office-365-users-specific-license-type-via-powershell/)

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake in my code, there is a set of parentheses necessary after the `-not`. Try the updated variant, please.

Comment: Ok so that did give me results not containing ENTERPRISEPACK but not how I was expecting. It's basically returned the exact same users but excluded the above product license text from the output for users that do have it assigned rather than excluding users from the results that simply don't have this value present. I've found another article that uses a different method which may help further. I'll report back if this proves useful.